Brackets after “There is no god but Allah”
A Person doesn’t understand what the brackets mean in the Quran, for example in [47:19]:

فَٱعْلَمْ أَنَّهُۥ لَآ إِلَـٰهَ إِلَّا ٱللَّهُ وَٱسْتَغْفِرْ لِذَنۢبِكَ وَلِلْمُؤْمِنِينَ وَٱلْمُؤْمِنَـٰتِ ۗ وَٱللَّهُ يَعْلَمُ مُتَقَلَّبَكُمْ وَمَثْوَىٰكُمْ
So, know ˹well, O  Prophet,˺ that there is no god ˹worthy of worship˺ except Allah. And seek forgiveness for your shortcomings and for ˹the sins of˺ the believing men and women. For Allah ˹fully˺ knows your movements and places of rest ˹O people˺.
Translated by Dr. Mustafa Khattab, The Clear Quran
https://quran.com/en/muhammad/19

How can I explain to the person that the brackets which state (none worthy of worship), do not mean the that there are gods besides Allah.

See https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/79929/ How to reason with someone doesn't seem on-topic. Personally I would just tell him that it means there are no gods other than Allah and move on.
